# javafxports gluon iOS textfield focus

Tags: gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I noticed some strange behavior interacting with requesting focus on text fields on iOS. I created a very basic view to illustrate my point. When the application loads, the TextField gains focus. After the textfield .setOnAction method has been called, the field should once again regain focus based on my code, but it does not. Pressing the "request focus" button should directly regain focus for the textfield, but it only works sometimes. If the "request focus" button is pressed immediately after the last focus object was the textfield, the textfield will not regain focus. If I click on something else, say the search button and then click on the "request focus" button, the textfield regains focus easily. I want to be able for the TextField to regain focus immediately after the .setOnAction method of the same textfield has been called, and I want the focus to go directly to the Textfield immediately after the Button has been clicked. These behaviors work accurately as they are supposed to on Desktop and Android, but do not work as intended on iOS.

```
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class BasicView extends View {

    public BasicView(String name) {
        super(name);

        javafx.scene.control.TextField label = new javafx.scene.control.TextField("");


        Button button = new Button("Request Focus");
        button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LANGUAGE));
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.requestFocus());

        VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setOnAction((e) -> {
            if (!label.getText().isEmpty()){
                controls.getChildren().add(new Label(label.getText()));
                label.setText("");
                label.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        setCenter(controls);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
    }

}
```

Comment: I currently don't understand the issue: You create a new `Label`, when hitting ENTER, with the text of the `TextField`. Why do you need to request focus on the field again? Does it not still have the focus?

Comment: Otherwise: We've resently released an App, written with JavaFXPorts and what I've learned: Sometimes (*tm*) I needed to explizitly wait for some milliseconds after another call... In your case you could try to add a `Task<Void>`, which waits for 10ms or so, and request the focus afterwards (`#onSucceed`) between the `#setText` and `#requestFocus`... Just an idea...